# Perl - Win32::AD::User - can't seem to figure out how to retrieve a DN

Tags: perl, active-directory

I'm trying to get the DN for a given username in a csv file using the Win32::ad::user module in Perl, but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Here's my code... (domain name has been replaced)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::AD::User;
use Text::CSV;
use Net::LDAP;

my $file = "Users.csv";
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

open (CSV, "<", $file) or die $!;

while (<CSV>) {
if ($csv->parse($_)) {
    my @username = $csv->fields();
    my $user = $username[0];
    my $adstring = join('', $user, ',user",',$user, '"');
    my $acdiruser=Win32::AD::User->new('WinNT://my.domain.EDU/ ',$user);
    $acdiruser->get_info();
    print join ("\n", $acdiruser->get_property( dn ));

}
}
close CSV;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

EDIT: The error was Bareword "dn" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at T:\Thunderbird Conversion\GetOU.pl line 22,  line 558. Execution of T:\Thunderbird Conversion\GetOU.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: "Can't seem to get the syntax right" is not an error message in Perl.  What happens when you run the code?  And of equal importance, why did you comment out `use strict;`?  Unless you're doing a throw-away one-liner, I'd recommend always using `strict` and `warnings` every single time.

Comment: Generally I do... guess I did that in a kitchen sink attempt to make it work. the error is Bareword "dn" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at T:\Thunderbird Conversion\GetOU.pl line 22, <DATA> line 558.Execution of T:\Thunderbird Conversion\GetOU.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: Right, so don't do that.  It appears as though the argument for the `get_property` method that you're looking for is a string.  So give it a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this was an issue with the Win32::AD::User module- When I was using Quotes, I was failing because I was trying to apply LDAP properties to a function that only accepts WinNT properties. I'll be using Net::Ldap instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think it maybe a typo.

```
$acdiruser->get_property( 'dn' );
```

regards,